# Laravel how to get an old input value for selectize input

Tags: validation, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using a [selectize](http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) for an input in my form, which is visible if a user has checked the checkbox first:

```
{!! Form::text('engagement_question', null, ['id' => 'engagement_question', 'placeholder' => 'Spørsmål for "bli med"']) !!}
```

So, on the page load I am checking if the checkbox was checked and then show the field based on that condition in my script.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    engagementCheckbox();
});

var engagementCheckbox = function() {
    if($('#engagement-checkbox').is(":checked")) {
        $('.engagement').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.engagement').hide();
        selectize.clear();
    }
}

$('#engagement-checkbox').change(function() {
    engagementCheckbox();
});

var items = icoop.engagements.map(function(x) {
    return { item: x };
});

var $select = $('#engagement_question').selectize({
    persist: false,
    maxItems: 1,
    options: items,
    labelField: "item",
    valueField: "item",
    sortField: 'item',
    searchField: 'item',
    create: true,
    render: {
      option_create: function(data, escape) {
        return '<div class="create">Nytt inlegg<strong> ' + escape(data.input) + '</strong>&hellip;</div>';
      }
    },
    onChange: function(value) {
      var unique = true;

      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if(items[i].item == value) {
          unique = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      if(!unique) {
        $select.next('.selectize-control').find('.item').addClass('item-background');
      }
    },
});

var selectize = $select[0].selectize;
```

I would like to also on a failed validation, show the old input value from a user if there was one for that field.  It is returning the input only if the user has selected one of the options from the `selectize items`, but not if the user has created one by himself.
I have tried with adding the `Input::old('engagement_question')` but wasn't working:

```
{!! Form::text('engagement_question', Input::old('engagement_question'), ['id' => 'engagement_question', 'placeholder' => 'Spørsmål for "bli med"']) !!}
```

But it is not working, how should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your Input::old is probably working ok, the issue seems to be that if the only option are to select from the 'item' array the newly added items won't be in this array yet and so will be remove from the input after selectize runs.

You could loop through the old('tags') and add a new item to the items array for the new ones.